# What happened to the four remaining men arrested as part of the plot against George Washington?

Tags: prisoners-of-war, george-washington

Brad Meltzer's book [The First Conspiracy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1250755867) on the plot to kill George Washington by members of his personal guard during the first year of the revolution states that 5 men were arrested for the plot. It was led by a Mr Green but the only person tried and hung on June 28 1777 was [Thomas Hickey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hickey_(soldier)#). The rest remained in prison.

Comment: Brief research  finds no mention of "Mr. Greene"  See [JAR](https://allthingsliberty.com/2014/07/plotting-the-sacricide-of-george-washington/) and [WIkipedia:Hickey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hickey_(soldier)#). [General Greene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathanael_Greene) lead the investigation, not the assassination.

Comment: @MCW William Green was involved, eventually testified against Hickey.

Answer (score 13):

It appears that [Thomas Hickey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hickey_(soldier)#Conspiracy) was merely arrested for passing counterfeit money, and was hung for a plot to pay Continental Army (US) soldiers to defect to the British. The assassination plot was never charged as or found to be anything more than a rumor. So **it doesn't look like anyone was ever arrested specifically for that.**

So what's all this historical smoke about?

Well, first off it appears to have been a rather influential rumor, rather akin to one of our modern-day conspiracy theories. An 19th century Washington Historian, William Sophie Baker, wrote about it as fact, although this same passage contained numerous outright factual errors. It seems likely he took documentation of the rumors as fact, rather than actually looking at court records.

So now we get to [Mr. Meltzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brad_Meltzer). He's a professional novelist and comic book author, specializing in "thrillers" for his non-fiction work. His educational training is as a lawyer.

For book in question, I find Amazon reviews, particularly the negative ones, to be most enlightening. [Here's one](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1RZREBSFQVOVX/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1250755867) I think pretty much sums it up, from a user identifying as "Louis L":

> **Misleading Title**
>  Reviewed in the United States on January 14, 2019
> Verified Purchase
> In the US we are subject to sensational, yet
> dubious, newspaper headlines & web postings. Now we can add
> questionable “history books” The Secret Plot to Kill George Washington
> is based on nothing more than rumor & conjecture. The author provides
> only a handful of source facts and turns it into 410 pages of
> speculation and repetitive prose. In the books “Author’s Notes” Brad
> Meltzer writes about reaching out to historian Joseph Ellis who tells
> him that this topic will “…always be elusive” & Meltzer states “He was
> right”. Then the question begs, why try to write a book?

I've heard tales of counterfeit money being purposely used to destabilize governments, so it seems quite plausible that Mr. Hickey was indeed a committed spy, rather than a suborned crook. However, he wasn't proven involved in anything directly violent, which is likely why people preferred the more lurid conspiracy theory to his actual proven conspiracies.

In short, this entire incident appears to be an artifact of what I like to call the [Liberty Valence](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Shot_Liberty_Valance#Dialogue) Principle of history: "When the legend becomes fact, print the legend."

Comment: Not taking credit for the concept of the Liberty Valence Effect. I got it from [Robert Wuhl's Assume the Position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assume_the_Position_with_Mr._Wuhl). However, the concept doesn't have a good referenceable presence on the internet.

Comment: It was more than just counterfeiting.   "More serious charges, however, were made against Hickey later on 17 June when Isaac Ketchum, another prisoner at the city hall, reported some indiscreet remarks that Hickey and Lynch had made in his presence about a conspiracy to enlist soldiers for the king and to sabotage Patriot efforts to defend New York City..." https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Washington/03-05-02-0073

Comment: Also, "In August 1784 Mathews told the British commission for American claims that during the war “he had formed a Plan for the taking Mr Washington & his Guard Prisoners but which was not effected by an unfortunate Discovery that was made of a Letter. One of the persons who was concern’d in the business (a Mr Hicky) was seized & executed” (Egerton, Royal Commission, 168)." https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Washington/03-05-02-0042

Comment: @DavePhD - These bits of info seem more appropriate to a new answer than a comment on another answer. (And yes, I freely admit I could have posted an answer that is wrong. Wouldn't be the first time.)

Comment: Still seems from reading that over that the original arrest that started everything (of Michael Lynch and Thomas Hickey according to that document) was indeed over counterfieting.